# multiprocessing.Pool imap feeds duplicate tasks to worker process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have 62 known files to be processed and using Pool/imap to speed things up. Unexpectedly and for unknown reason imap started feeding the same file name to the same worker process multiple times. Code:

```
def worker_proc(file):
    procname = current_process().name
    info("{} {}".format(procname, file))
    return 1  # Normally this is the count of records processed.

files = ['UOUT.DBF', 'OUT2.DBF', 'OUT3.DBF', 'OUT4.DBF', 'OUT5.DBF', 'OUT6.DBF', 'OUT7.DBF', 'OUT8.DBF', 'OUT9.DBF', 'OUTA.DBF', 'OUTB.DBF', 'OUTC.DBF', 'OUTD.DBF', 'OUTE.DBF', 'OUTF.DBF', 'OUTG.DBF', 'OUTH.DBF', 'OUTI.DBF', 'OUTJ.DBF', 'OUTK.DBF', 'OUTL.DBF', 'OUTM.DBF', 'OUTN.DBF', 'OUTO.DBF', 'OUTP.DBF', 'OUTQ.DBF', 'OUTR.DBF', 'OUTS.DBF', 'NORD.DBF', 'ORD2.DBF', ...'ORDY.DBF']
with Pool(os.cpu_count() // 2) as p:
    ret = p.imap(worker_proc, files)
    for n, cnt in enumerate(ret):
        info("FILE {} of {} COMPLETE, cnt {}".format(n, len(files), cnt))
```

Here's the log generated by worker_proc info():

```
02:18:30 SpawnPoolWorker-8  UOUT.DBF
02:18:32 SpawnPoolWorker-12 UOUT2.DBF
02:18:33 SpawnPoolWorker-2  UOUT3.DBF
02:18:33 SpawnPoolWorker-13 UOUT4.DBF
02:18:35 SpawnPoolWorker-7  UOUT5.DBF
02:18:38 SpawnPoolWorker-3  UOUT6.DBF
02:18:42 SpawnPoolWorker-4  UOUT7.DBF
02:18:44 SpawnPoolWorker-1  UOUT8.DBF
02:18:48 SpawnPoolWorker-11 UOUT9.DBF
02:18:48 SpawnPoolWorker-6  UOUTA.DBF
02:18:53 SpawnPoolWorker-5  UOUTB.DBF
02:18:57 SpawnPoolWorker-10 UOUTC.DBF
02:18:58 SpawnPoolWorker-9  UOUTD.DBF
03:27:59 SpawnPoolWorker-12 UOUTE.DBF
03:33:07 SpawnPoolWorker-7  UOUT5.DBF
03:35:48 SpawnPoolWorker-3  UOUT6.DBF
03:42:58 SpawnPoolWorker-9  UOUTF.DBF
03:44:45 SpawnPoolWorker-13 UOUT4.DBF
03:50:04 SpawnPoolWorker-4  UOUTG.DBF
03:51:27 SpawnPoolWorker-11 UOUTH.DBF
03:54:43 SpawnPoolWorker-2  UOUT3.DBF
03:56:46 SpawnPoolWorker-6  UOUTI.DBF
03:56:47 SpawnPoolWorker-1  UOUTJ.DBF
03:57:23 SpawnPoolWorker-8  UOUT.DBF
04:00:28 SpawnPoolWorker-10 UOUTK.DBF
04:02:19 SpawnPoolWorker-5  UOUTL.DBF
05:00:56 SpawnPoolWorker-7  UOUT5.DBF
05:01:51 SpawnPoolWorker-2  UOUT3.DBF
05:03:00 SpawnPoolWorker-12 UOUTM.DBF
05:04:38 SpawnPoolWorker-13 UOUT4.DBF
05:08:12 SpawnPoolWorker-1  UOUTN.DBF
05:10:11 SpawnPoolWorker-5  UOUTO.DBF
05:10:30 SpawnPoolWorker-3  UOUTP.DBF
05:15:35 SpawnPoolWorker-10 UOUTQ.DBF
05:22:42 SpawnPoolWorker-4  UOUTR.DBF
05:24:22 SpawnPoolWorker-6  UOUTS.DBF
05:25:28 SpawnPoolWorker-11 ORD.DBF
05:27:51 SpawnPoolWorker-8  ORD2.DBF
...
```

You can see that after 'UOUTF.DBF' Pool starts feeding the same file names to the same processes causing havoc in the rest of my program.

UPDATE: This program has been working in production flawlessly for many months. For this particular workload it fails every time. Full run is ~7 hours on Win Server 2012. Unfortunately when I comment out worker code, as with the code above, it works correctly.

Previous run (#7) for comparison:

```
00:17:38 SpawnPoolWorker-5  UOUT.DBF
00:17:40 SpawnPoolWorker-2  UOUT2.DBF
00:17:42 SpawnPoolWorker-10 UOUT3.DBF
00:17:42 SpawnPoolWorker-13 UOUT4.DBF
00:17:43 SpawnPoolWorker-4  UOUT5.DBF
00:17:48 SpawnPoolWorker-11 UOUT6.DBF
00:17:53 SpawnPoolWorker-12 UOUT7.DBF
00:18:03 SpawnPoolWorker-1  UOUT8.DBF
00:18:05 SpawnPoolWorker-8  UOUT9.DBF
00:18:06 SpawnPoolWorker-7  UOUTA.DBF
00:18:09 SpawnPoolWorker-6  UOUTB.DBF
00:18:10 SpawnPoolWorker-3  UOUTC.DBF
00:18:11 SpawnPoolWorker-9  UOUTD.DBF
01:20:52 SpawnPoolWorker-8  UOUT9.DBF
01:20:53 SpawnPoolWorker-8  UOUTE.DBF
01:22:44 SpawnPoolWorker-13 UOUT4.DBF
01:22:44 SpawnPoolWorker-13 UOUTF.DBF
01:23:11 SpawnPoolWorker-5  UOUT.DBF
01:23:11 SpawnPoolWorker-5  UOUTG.DBF
...
```

Run #6 for comparison:

```
00:21:04 SpawnPoolWorker-2  UOUT.DBF
00:21:04 SpawnPoolWorker-6  UOUT2.DBF
00:21:05 SpawnPoolWorker-11 UOUT3.DBF
00:21:06 SpawnPoolWorker-12 UOUT4.DBF
00:21:06 SpawnPoolWorker-4  UOUT5.DBF
00:21:06 SpawnPoolWorker-3  UOUT6.DBF
00:21:07 SpawnPoolWorker-5  UOUT7.DBF
00:21:07 SpawnPoolWorker-9  UOUT8.DBF
00:21:07 SpawnPoolWorker-10 UOUT9.DBF
00:21:07 SpawnPoolWorker-1  UOUTA.DBF
00:21:08 SpawnPoolWorker-13 UOUTB.DBF
00:21:09 SpawnPoolWorker-7  UOUTC.DBF
00:21:10 SpawnPoolWorker-8  UOUTD.DBF
01:02:27 SpawnPoolWorker-9  UOUTE.DBF
01:17:58 SpawnPoolWorker-7  UOUTC.DBF
01:17:58 SpawnPoolWorker-7  UOUTF.DBF
01:18:09 SpawnPoolWorker-12 UOUT4.DBF
01:18:09 SpawnPoolWorker-12 UOUTG.DBF
01:18:24 SpawnPoolWorker-3  UOUT6.DBF
01:18:24 SpawnPoolWorker-3  UOUTH.DBF
01:19:55 SpawnPoolWorker-1  UOUTA.DBF
01:19:55 SpawnPoolWorker-1  UOUTI.DBF
01:21:20 SpawnPoolWorker-8  UOUTD.DBF
01:21:20 SpawnPoolWorker-8  UOUTJ.DBF
01:21:57 SpawnPoolWorker-11 UOUTK.DBF
01:24:52 SpawnPoolWorker-5  UOUTL.DBF
01:25:53 SpawnPoolWorker-13 UOUTM.DBF
01:29:55 SpawnPoolWorker-4  UOUTN.DBF
01:31:13 SpawnPoolWorker-10 UOUTO.DBF
01:31:57 SpawnPoolWorker-6  UOUTP.DBF
01:32:12 SpawnPoolWorker-2  UOUTQ.DBF
...
```

**Final Update: Found the issue!**

```
def worker_proc(file):
    procname = current_process().name
    info("{} {}".format(procname, file))
    ...
    try:
        engine.execute(ins)
    except Exception as e:
        if "deadlocked" in e.args[0] or "duplicate" in e.args[0]:
            warning("Deadlocked, restarting worker_proc {}".format(file))
            return worker_proc(file)
```

In my zeal to edit out irrelevant code I nicked the cause. Also should not restart the job if it fell through because of a duplicate. It appeared that duplicate issue was caused by double-submitting a file, while the cause was mostly in poor quality input files.

Also can add an argument like:

```
def worker_proc(file, attempt_no=0):
    ...
    except Exception as e:
        if attempt_no > 2:
            raise
        return worker_proc(file, attempt_no + 1)
```

This makes recursion more explicit and limits number of retries.

Comment: Are you certain all file names are unique? Have you tried using a set to make sure?

Comment: Yes, `len(set(files))` is 62.

Comment: What do you then do with your ret? Has this code worked and then suddenly stopped working? Could you please edit your post to add the part where you actually execute your tasks by using the iterator generated by `p.imap()`

Comment: @Hannu I don't do much with the iterator, code shown.

Comment: Use a recipe [like this one](https://seasonofcode.com/posts/python-multiprocessing-and-exceptions.html) to wrap your worker function bodies in try/except blocks to capture exceptions in the workers that may not be getting propagated to the main process. I can't think of any reason they *wouldn't* cause an exception in the main process, but that would be my next debugging step. Just confirm you don't have hidden errors in your workers.

Comment: Also, do you get the same result if you reduce the size of your list of files? Do the repeats happen with the same files every time? See if you can narrow it down to exactly which files trigger this error.

Comment: @skrrgwasme I had 8 runs so far and it looks like the mess begins after the first 13 file assignments, which happens to be the number of worker processes.

Comment: @skrrgwasme I posted a couple of logs from previous runs to show a better picture.

Comment: This is an interesting problem... It's not the same files every time. Could you tell me a bit about what the file processing workers actually do? Like, are you moving, deleting, or renaming files? The inconsistency of the results combined with the tendency for it to occur once all workers are engaged suggests some kind of race condition. Do your workers use any regular expressions or path manipulations that could have bugs causing them to modify the wrong file or directory, in turn causing an error in different worker that needed that file (which could then cause the job to be relaunched)?

Comment: Also, do you see the same behavior if you temporarily dump the multiprocessing and just run [itertools.imap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) on the same file set? If that works without a problem, that would suggest that the issue is a multiprocessing-induced race condition. If you have a less-complicated programming error in there, normal sequential execution might make it easier to see.

Comment: @skrrgwasme worker code is relatively simple: it reads the DBF file record by record, and inserts each record into multiple tables of an SQL database.

Comment: Unfortunately I think I'm out of suggestions to make without seeing the code itself. I've been unable to recreate any duplicate job submission issues with the pool.

Comment: Thank you, @skrrgwasme, I will make an update when I find the issue.